# Insert Excel chart into Word template

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, templates, microsoft-office-2013

I want to create a Word template. Is it possible, that template will take information from another Excel file automaticaly? And can it use charts?

User story:
The user should open the template, choose Excel file source (or it could be at predefined location). Charts should be imported into template. User will only need to fill some text fields and save/print document.

I don't know if functionality exists in Office, that would let me accomplish this. Please let me know, if Word has such functionality, how is it called and what should I search for.

I use Office 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go two ways with Microsoft Office here.

1. You can *embed* the Excel file inside the Word document. You won't see the Excel file - it is part of the Word document or template. You can double-click on the Excel element (a table or a chart) and edit the data in an Excel user interface.
2. The other way to do it, is to create the Excel file and link it to a Word document. Every update of the Excel file is reflected in the Word document, once it is opened or printed.

Both methods are described in [this Microsoft Office article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Link-or-embed-an-Excel-worksheet-41bf021e-ba7c-44ef-9914-0d7e88062257).